# kotlin map add value if doesn't equal

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a `val valuesMap = mutableMapOf<String, String>()`
I want to add new value if keys of map doesn't equalsIgnoreCase new value.

```
if(!valuesMap.keys.equalsIgnoreKeys("value")) {
 valuesMap.put("value", null)
}
```

Something like this, but in kotlin we have only equals method for keys.

Comment: Are you sure a Map is the best choice here? Looks like you are utilising it as an Array.

Comment: Why not use hashset instead for unique entries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use a specific map for your use case:

```
val caseInsensitive = TreeMap<String, String>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER)
```

The following constructor is used here:

> **public TreeMap(Comparator comparator)**
>
> Constructs a new, empty tree map, ordered according to the given comparator. All keys inserted into the map must be mutually comparable by the given comparator: comparator.compare(k1, k2) must not throw a ClassCastException for any keys k1 and k2 in the map. If the user attempts to put a key into the map that violates this constraint, the put(Object key, Object value) call will throw a ClassCastException.
>
> **Parameters**:
>       comparator - the comparator that will be used to order this map. If null, the natural ordering of the keys will be used.

Comment: I mean if map have already contained <key = "key", null> and i will try to add <key = "key", value = "value">, what will be ?

Comment: it will be "value"; the comparator only applies to keys: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html

Answer (score 4):

This iterates through the key set and compares lower-cased keys to the given term (new key).

```
val map: MutableMap<String, String?> = mutableMapOf()
val term = "value"
val contains = map.keys.any { key ->
    key.toLowerCase() == term.toLowerCase()
}
if (!contains) {
    map.put(term, null)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to use `containsKey()`

```
if (!valuesMap.containsKey("value")) {
    valuesMap.put("value", null)
}
```

**Edit 1**
according to [link](https://github.com/jkcclemens/khttp/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/khttp/structures/maps/CaseInsensitiveMutableMap.kt) in comment , you can use

```
String valueByKey = valuesMap.filter { 
                                it.key.equals("keyValue", ignoreCase = true) 
                             }.map { it.key }.firstOrNull()
if(valueByKey==null){
    valuesMap.put("keyValue", null)
}
```

Comment: and what about containsIgnoreCase ?

Comment: if you want to use case insensivemutablemap you can check https://github.com/jkcclemens/khttp/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/khttp/structures/maps/CaseInsensitiveMutableMap.kt. But there is no containsIgnoreCase method for maps. Because for `String` keys every combination of `String` are different keys. For example; "Value", "VAlue", "value" are different keys.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add a key which lower cased is not yet in the map you can apply a filter to the keys using a predicate which lower cases all keys. If the predicate returns no results you can insert the pair, otherwise not.

Something along the lines:

```
private fun addIfNotLowerExists(map: MutableMap<String, String>, candidate: Pair<String, String>) {
    if (map.filter { s -> s.key.toLowerCase().equals(candidate.first.toLowerCase()) }.keys.isEmpty()) {
        map[candidate.first] = candidate.second
    }
}
```

Here is a running example of the code:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val map = mutableMapOf<String, String>(Pair("k1", "v1"), Pair("K2", "v2"))
    addIfNotLowerExists(map, Pair("k2", "v2_1"))
    addIfNotLowerExists(map, Pair("k3", "v3"))
    println(map)
}

private fun addIfNotLowerExists(map: MutableMap<String, String>, candidate: Pair<String, String>) {
    if (map.filter { s -> s.key.toLowerCase().equals(candidate.first.toLowerCase()) }.keys.isEmpty()) {
        map[candidate.first] = candidate.second
    }
}
```

This prints out:

```
{k1=v1, K2=v2, k3=v3}
```

As you can see the value pair `{k2:v2_1}` is not inserted, because the key *K2* is already in the map.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to use only lower case keys in the map, otherwise you can do this

```
valuesMap.keys.map { it.toLowerCase() }.find { it == "value".toLowerCase() } ?: valuesMap.put("value", null)
```